# Store SQL Query into MultiDimensional Array

Tags: vb.net, oledb

A the title suggests I am attempting to store a query into a 2-D array. I must be doing something wrong as it seems it is only storing the last row in the array in the (0,0) through (0,5) column (i guess thats just the first column lol)

Before it is suggested that I use a list, my next step is to randomize the array to output something different each time its called. That part i have figured out but I keep stumbling on this read to array nonsense.

Here is what I currently have:

```
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Documents\test.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    Dim Str As String
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim myArray(2, 5) As String

    myConnection.Open()
    Str = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer FROM Critters;"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        myArray(i, 0) = CType(dr("Question"), String)
        myArray(i, 1) = CType(dr("Answer1"), String)
        myArray(i, 2) = CType(dr("Answer2"), String)
        myArray(i, 3) = CType(dr("Answer3"), String)
        myArray(i, 4) = CType(dr("Answer4"), String)
        myArray(i, 5) = CType(dr("CorrectAnswer"), String)
        i = i + 1
    End While

    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: If you declare and initialize to 0 the variable i at every loop what else do you expect to happen here? Move the declaration and the initialization outside the loop. By the way, do you know that a DataTable is just a glorified array with a lot of extra gadget to work with data?

Comment: god f'ing dammit LOL

Comment: @Steve if you post as answer ill give you due credit

Comment: You'd be much better off normalizing that table - you could easily repeat answers and store it more compactly

Comment: (almost) Anytime you have columns named xxx1 xxx2 xxx3, you have missed a relationship in the DB design.  As is, it is rigid: 4 candidate answers **and** one of them is repeated as the correct one.  An answer table would be more flexible with one candidate tagged as correct for this question

Comment: Yes as soon as I realized you were talking about RD concepts I understood. This would potentially make me rewrite my silly for fun code but i guess its for the best since i can leanr more that way

Comment: rather than an array, you can store it in a Datatable and use them in random order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple error. The declaration and the initialization of the variable i should go outside the loop

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
While dr.Read()
  ....
```

But I prefer a lot to use a DataTable with code like this

```
Dim dt = new DataTable()
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
```

Now you can use the DataTable more or less like a two dimensional array

```
Dim question as string = dt.Rows(0)(0)

for each row as DataRow in dt.Rows
   Console.WriteLine("Question = " & row(0).ToString())
Next
```

Comment: this might prove be to be more simplistic. Thanks